# XCode 9.1 Linker error related to bitcode in facebook sdk 7.11 from Unity 5.6.4 project

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I created a new scene in Unity 5.6.4 p1 and imported the facebook sdk 7.11.0. I'm able to build iOS from unity, but trying to build in XCode 9.1 fails with the error:

ld: '/Users/joshwagner/Code/FacebookSDKBuildTest/iOSBuild/Frameworks/FacebookSDK/Plugins/iOS/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit(FBSDKAppInviteContent.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I checked the upgrade guide here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/upgrading-7.x
and it sounds like my version of Unity should be compatible.

I've also read that the facebook sdk has been compiled with bitcode enabled since version 4.

I've tried turning off bitcode support on my main project which causes other issues unfortunately.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is a bug in Facebook SDK for Unity 7.11.0. Switching to the previous version (7.10) compiles without any problems. I've submitted a bug report to Facebook, and will use version 7.10 instead.